# How to redirect all requests within a subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website called mydumbwebsite.com/. In my root folder, I have various folders, one of them being "stuff". This folder is directly accessible with mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/. I want to create an .htaccess file that redirects everything that goes into this subfolder and **only** this subfolder, so these urls:

1. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test
2. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test/
3. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test.php
4. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test.php?test=yes
5. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test2.php (doesn't exist)
6. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test2.php?test=yes (doesn't exist)
7. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test/moar
8. mydumbwebsite.com/stuff/test/moar/tests.php

... should all redirect to the index.php file of the folder "stuff", even if the file/folder they point to exists.

Some additional context: despite my made up example, I encountered this problem on localhost. I have many different projects and I don't want the .htaccess of one project interfere with the other projects. I tried [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/), but it keeps redirecting me to the xampp homepage:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried changing it to this, but that couldn't cover all instances, such as nr. 2, 3 and 4:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /stuff/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Note that `!-d` and `!-f` make sure that the rule only applies if the request is _not_ an actual existing file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the conditions `!-d` and `!-f`, which say "Don't apply the rule on existing files and directories". You also need to remove `RewriteBase /`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The file should be located under `/suff/.htaccess`.

The following rules do also work for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [END]
```

Regarding your comment:

Usually I would create a `public` folder and put anything that should be accessed directly (`public/css/`, `public/js`, `public/img` etc.) in it. And whitelist it as following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^public/ -  [END] # allow direct access on public folder
RewriteRule ^ index.php [END] # anything else will be directed to index.php
```

You can of course whitelist multiple directories the same way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css/ - [END]
RewriteRule ^img/ - [END]
RewriteRule ^js/  - [END]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [END]
```

Or something like you suggested in the comment:

```
RewriteRule ^(scripts|styles|morefoldernames)($|/) - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally something that actually works! However... now I got an unexpected problem... it redirects all my css and javascript embeds, too. Opening up my javascript file leads me back to my index.php file. I guess I should've been more specific, those of course still need to work the same way, or else my page is broken. How can I set an exception to certain folders?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out: you need to set *RewriteRule ^(scripts|styles|morefoldernames)($|/) - [L]* after *RewriteEngine On*. Can you add this to your answer?

Comment: I would rather use whitlisting instead of blacklisting. It's too easy to forget to blacklist something, and people get access to your internal files. But I'm not sure how to write a whitelisting `RewriteCond` yet.

Comment: Alright, I'll still select your answer and give you the bounty, since you've helped me get where I want so far. If you find out a better way than what I proposed, feel free to add it later.

Comment: Just realized that your rule is actually a whitelisting rule - not blacklisting.

Comment: Yeah, I was really confused why you called it blacklisting, but I just assumed I was wrong since I'm so clueless with .htaccess XD

Comment: I've read "scripts", and thought of PHP scripts, but you probably mean JS. Not that I'm an expert. Rewrite rules can be so "magic" - So I also don't ask questions, when something works for me :-)

Comment: Yeah, scripts was for JavaScript stuff only. I have another folder for php called views, which of course wouldn't be in the list of folders in the whitelist.

Comment: Anyway - I'm glad you figured that out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is late, so my brain could be muddled about this, but surely you simply want everything in stuff to be redirected to index.php, no if's or buts.

Then the below should work, provided it has "/stuff/" in the URL. I'm guessing that you aren't bothered about query strings etc either, if so, then you'll need to modify the index.php below to index.php?$1 and the flags to [QSA, NC, L].

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/stuff/?$  /stuff/index.php [NC,L]
```

Check that your root .htaccess file has the line "RewriteOptions InheritDown" somewhere in it, that way the .htaccess file for each subfolder should be covered.

Comment: `?` is a single character wildcard. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/stuff/(.+)$ /stuff/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all... what am I missing? Did you have to change some settings or something?

Comment: @noClue sorry for the late response this is something that you would put inside your `root` or `public` directory where `stuff` would normally exist. The answer provided by Paul is thorough and more close to what you want. As written before the above snippet would be written in your root `htaccess` file in your `public_html`.directory.